# Is it possible to name a dictionary from user input in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

It's sort of a dynamic variable creation but I just want the name of the dictionary to be called what the user wants it to be called. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a dictionary of user_input => data (data can be a dictionary itself!), not "dynamic variables". The user ***should not care*** what the actual dictionary variable is called unless they are doing something source-code related. If this is case, make sure it is explicitly discussed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please complete your [tour] and consult the [ask] section and the [help] to understand what is the expected question format.  Namely a [MCVE] of your attempt and the input/output.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? What are you trying to achieve and why? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should not use dynamic variables.

Comment: I'm trying to create multiple to do lists that can called to add or remove items from them.